Commutativity of a diagram in the proof of the Atiyah-Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch Theorem in Karoubi's "$K$-Theory"
I'm reading the book about $K$-theory written by Max Karoubi ($K$-Theory: An Introduction). In Chapter V Section 4.17, I'm stuck with the proof that the following diagram commutes:

Here $X$ and $Y$ are assumed to be compact oriented differential finite dimensional CW-complexes satisfying $Dim(X) - Dim(Y) = 0$ (mod 2). The map $p\colon Y \times S^{2n} \to Y $ is the projection map and $Ch: X \to H^*(X; \mathbb{Q})$ is the Chern character. The $K$-theoretic Gysin homomorphism $p_*^K $ is defined as follows:
First, choose an embedding $i$ sending $Y \times S^{2n}$ into the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$. Then, we have an embedding $p \times i\colon Y \times S^{2n} \to Y \times \mathbb{R}^{2m}$. Its normal bundle's class in $K_{\mathbb{R}}(Y \times S^{2n})$ is to be of $[(p \times i)^*(T(Y \times \mathbb{R}^{2m}))] - [T(Y \times S^{2n})] = [\pi_Y^* TY ]  + [2m] - [\pi_Y^{*}TY ] - [\pi_{S^{2n}}^*TS^{2n}] = [2m-2]$ because the sphere's normal bundle is trivial. So the $\mathrm{spin}^c$ structure is given to be trivial. With this, we have a Thom isomorphism that allows us to regard $K(X) \cong K(N)$. Take a tubular neighborhood in the embedding $Y \times \mathbb{R}^{2m}$ and we will write it as $N$ (abuse of notation). The Gysin homomorphism is the composition of the following homomorphisms:
$$
    K(X) \to K(N) \to K(Y \times \mathbb{R}^{2m}) \to K(Y)
$$
The first map is the Thom isomorphism, and the next is given by the natural map $g\colon \widehat{(Y\times \mathbb{R}^{2m}}) \to \widehat{N}$ such that $x \to \infty$ if x is not in $N$ and $x \to x $ if $x$ is in $N$ where $\hat{X}$ is the one point compactification of $X$. The final one is induced from Bott periodicity.
It is enough to show that for the map $\pi\colon S^{2n} \to \{ *\}$ (a one point set) the relation
$$
    Ch(\pi^K_*(x))  = \pi_*^H (Ch(x))
$$
holds. I've considered the embedding of $S^{2n}$ into the $\mathbb{R}^{2n+2}$ given by $s \to (s,0) \in \mathbb{R}^{2n+1} \times \mathbb{R} $. I guess that it would be true that the Gysin homomorphism is giving the reduced Grothendieck group part so that it maps $K(S^{2n}) \cong \tilde{K}(S^{2n}) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ to $K(\{* \}) \cong \tilde{K}(S^{2n+2}) \cong \tilde{K}(S^{2n})$ but can't find the appropriate reason why. Would you help me?

You should clean up your $X$'s and $Y$'s. There's no $X$'s in the diagram, but then some suddenly appear in your argument without further introduction.

If your reduction to $S^{2n} \to {}$ is correct, then I think a brute force analysis does the trick: The pushforward $\pi_^K$ is given by the composite $K(S^{2n}) \to K(S^{2n} \times B_{1/2}^{2(m - n)}(0)) \xrightarrow{g} K(\mathbb{R}^{2m}) \to K(*)$, where the first and last maps are isomorphisms (here $B_{1/2}^{2(m - n)}(0)$ is the open ball of dimension $2(m - n)$). Thus we are done if we can show that $g$ is nullhomotopic, and this is follows from the fact that $S^{2n}$ is nullbordant after observing that the construction inducing it is precisely the P-T construction for $S^{2n}$.

(I had to abbreviate Pontryagin-Thom to P-T for space reasons.) This is obviously not what's intended, but maybe it's good enough for government work. I can also offer another proof using stable homotopy theory and the fact that the Chern character is induced by a map of ring spectra, although that would be too much to spell out in a comment (and certainly even further from Karoubi's text).

Thank you so much. I think this is the perfect reference.

@BenSteffan I have a question on your comment. First, I’m not familiar with the Thom-Pontryagin construction. So I want to understand the meaning of g being nullhomotopic. If you meant that $g \colon S^{2m} \to S^{2n} \times \bar{B}^2(m-n)}/S^{2n} \times S^{2(m-n)}$ is nullhomotopic in algebraic topology, then doesn’t it identically map $K(S^{2n} \times B^{2(m-n)}_{1/2}) \to K(\mathbb{R}^{2m})$ by zero?

It means it factors as $K(S^{2n} \times B_{1/2}^{2(m - n)}) \to K({*}) \to K(\mathbb{R}^{2m})$. When I wrote the comment I thought this was the "right" thing but now I'm not quite sure anymore. I'll have to think about it.
